# PHP Generated product pages e.g: Page: [1] 2 3 4

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a product page that is generated using WordPress to get the products and display them, however I want to be able to limit the amount visible at one time.

WordPress/PHP generation code:

```
$pages = get_pages(array('parent' => $post->ID, 'hierarchical' => 0, 'number' => $postsPerPage, 'sort_order' => 'ASC', 'sort_column' => 'menu_order'));
foreach ($pages as $page) {
    $content = '<div class="pcp-product-display">
                    <div class="pcp-left-product-display-container">
                        <h2>' . $page->post_title . '</h2>';
    $content .=         '<div class="pcp-img-container">'. get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail') .'</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pcp-right-product-display-container">
                        <div class="pcp-product-excerpt">' . get_field('page_excerpt', $page->ID) . '</div>';
    $content .=         '<div class="price"><p> &pound;' . get_field('product_price', $page->ID) . '</p></div>
                        <div class="pcp-product-display-cta">
                            <a href="' . get_permalink($page->ID) . '"><h3>More Information</h3></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!--
                        -->';
                echo $content;
            }
```

Here is what the page looks like:

[image: this]

I have got the "Items per page" at the top working, but I'd like that to work in conjunction with the pages.

I would like to do this using "product pages", for example you can see products 1-10 and there are 3 further pages to cycle through. (`Page: [1] 2 3 4`)

I'm not sure how I would go about getting the "product pages" to work.

Would it be best to use AJAX and grab, say, products 11-20 and then display them?

Or should I use PHP and WordPress?

If you need more information I should be able to provide it.

Answer (score 0):

`get_pages()` also has "offset" parameter which you should use to skip some content if you are not displaying first page. AJAX or not - depends on what you need.
You can pass page parameter trough url (those pager links) and in that case URL containing page number can be shared. But if you don't want that you can use AJAX to. It maybe gives nicer results, but is a bit hard to achieve. I vote for non-ajax solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! If I understand you correctly, I should set the "offset" to a variable that changes depending on which page they're looking at (And I think that would also work with the "Items Per page" selector as well). I'll give it a try now and get back to you!

Comment: Yes, that's the point. You generate those pager the links (1,2,3)..and they will all lead to same page except they will have that page parameter, that will be different for every one of them.
So, you have to collect that parameter and multiply it with number of posts per page to get that offset. Like, if you are currently on page 2 and you have 10 posts per page you have to set offset to 1x10 (since first  page is actually zero page - starting from zero...).

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages

Answer (score 0):

Check out the functions I'm using for generating page links. You should call get_paging().
- prefix is part of links that should be added before the part pager creates,
- curr is the number of current page
- cnt is the total number of pages.

It's not perfect but it works for me. Feel free to adjust it to your needs.

```
function get_paging ($prefix, $curr, $cnt){

    if($cnt<2) return ''; // no paging needed
    $prev = '&laquo; PREV';
    $next = 'NEXT &raquo;';

    $ret='<div id="pager">';

    if ($curr > 1) $ret.='<a class="pagingPrev" href="'.$prefix.''.($curr-1).'">'.$prev.'</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'; // prev: -1 leap
    else $ret.='<span class="pagingPrevDisabled">'.$prev.'</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';

    $start  = 1; // middle range links
    $end = $cnt;

    for ($i=$start; $i <= $end ; $i++){
        $ret.=paging_number($i,$curr,$prefix); // middle range
    }

    if ($cnt > $curr) $ret.='<a class="pagingNext" href="'.$prefix.''.($curr+1).'">'.$next.'</a>'; // next: +1 leap
    else $ret.='<span class="pagingNextDisabled">'.$next.'</span>';
    $ret.='</div>';
    return $ret;
}

function paging_number($num, $curr,$prefix){
    if ($num == (int)$curr)
        return '<span class="currPage">'.$num.'</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'; // not a link
    else
        return '<a href="'.$prefix.$num.'">'.$num.'</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'; // link
}
```